# How to Map one rdd to another with Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have `rdd1` which have `labels(0,1,4)` and another `rdd2` in which i have text. I want to map `rdd1` with `rdd2` such that `row1` of `rdd1` is mapped with `row1` of `rdd2` and so on.

I have tried:

```
rdd2.join(rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[0:])))
```

It gives me error:

```
RDD is empty.
```

Can someone please guide me here?
Sample Output: rdd1- **labels** & rdd2-**Text**

```
rdd1       rdd2

0   i hate painting i have white paint all over my hands.

0   Bawww I need a haircut  No1 could fit me in before work tonight. Sigh.

4   I had a great day

1   what is life.

4   He sings so good

1   i need to go to sleep  ....goodnight
```

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIdgY.png)

Comment: are 0,1,4 on the same row? and what is the value for rdd2? and what is your expected output?

Comment: rdd2 have text. i want to map the predicted labels from rdd1 to rdd2 correspondingly from row1.
Different rows have different labels. 0,1,4 are three categories

Comment: can you clarify it a little bit more by giving sample rdd2 and expected output?

Comment: Below is the kind out output i am looking for:
rdd1  rdd2
0 i hate painting i have white paint all over my hands 
1 what is life?
0 I need a new phone..... I also need to go to sleep! Ewwie school tomorrow. 
4 I had a really good day
0 Blah, time for bed I suppose. Seeing my friends back off to Ohio in the morning 
1 i need to go to sleep  ....goodnight

Comment: @RahulAnand can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49367123/edit) your question and post that sample output as formatted code? It's very hard to decipher as a comment.

Comment: I will add my sample output in question itself.

Comment: @RahulAnand please don't post it as a picture. Post it at formatted text. Read more on [why posting images in your question is bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5858851).

Comment: @pault I have posted my sample output as formatted text.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have edited my question with the desired sample output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rdd1` as

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(0,0,4,1,4,1))
```

and `rdd2` as

```
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List("i hate painting i have white paint all over my hands.",
  "Bawww I need a haircut  No1 could fit me in before work tonight. Sigh.",
  "I had a great day",
  "what is life.",
  "He sings so good",
  "i need to go to sleep  ....goodnight"))
```

> > I want to map rdd1 with rdd2 such that row1 of rdd1 is mapped with row1 of rdd2 and so on.

**using zip function**

A simple `zip` function should meet your rquirement

```
rdd1.zip(rdd2)
```

which would give you output as

```
(0,i hate painting i have white paint all over my hands.)
(0,Bawww I need a haircut  No1 could fit me in before work tonight. Sigh.)
(4,I had a great day)
(1,what is life.)
(4,He sings so good)
(1,i need to go to sleep  ....goodnight)
```

**zipWithIndex and join**

This approach would give you the same output as explained above using `zip` (and this method is expensive as well)

```
rdd1.zipWithIndex().map(_.swap).join(rdd2.zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)).map(_._2)
```

I hope the answer is helpful